# How to upload files based on primary key of foreignkey?

Tags: django, django-models

Basically I am trying to create an app which can allow user to upload lessons material such as documents on their specific posts. However, I am unsure of how I should display the documents uploaded based on the primary key of the posts. As of now, my posts are displaying all the documents that are being uploaded by the particular user.

This is my 'Post' model

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default0.jpg', upload_to='course_image/')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is my 'Lesson' model

```py
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="lesson/pdf")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('lesson_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

This is my Class-based listview that is supposed to display the uploaded lessons based on the posts:

```py
class LessonListView(ListView):
model = Lesson
template_name = 'store/uploaded_lesson.html'
context_object_name = 'lesson'

def get_queryset(self):
    self.post = get_object_or_404(post, name=self.kwargs['post'])
    return Lesson.objects.filter(post=self.post)
```

```html
{% extends "store/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="main">
    <table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
      <tr>          
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for lesson in lesson %}
      <tr>
        <td>
            {% if lesson.file %}
                <img src="{{ lesson.file.url }}"  style="width:100px;">
            {% else %}   
            {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need another model for the material they are uploading. Something like:

```
class UploadedPostMaterial(models.Model):
    content= models.TextField()
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This model will contain the uploaded data and tie it to a post. Now when you display all or specific Posts in your app, you can select the related content for each post and display the uploaded content.

Comment: Note that you would only need `UploadedPostMaterial.user` if it was different than `UploadedPostMaterial.post.author`.

Comment: @dfundako thanks for the quick reply, I was still editing and uploading my code on this post. The part whereby I am struggling with the most is to call my content on my listview template shown above. As of now I am using lesson.file in my template which is clearly wrong but I dont know what is the correct way to reference to the correct files that are related to the post. Should I use some if conditions?

Comment: @namespace97 Add the view logic that is calling the template you put into your original post. You most likely need to have a view that contains context that will include the posts and the Lessons and render that context into your template.

Comment: @dfundako Hi thanks for the quick reply again. Cos I pretty new to Django and information on class-based view is quite hard to find but am I supposed to use get_context_data() in my listview, and if so, how should I associate the uploaded material to the primary key of my ForeignKey which is Post.

Comment: @namespace97 Have you reviewed this part of the Django Tutorial? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects

Comment: @dfundako Hi I just reviewed the documentation and included a queryset() into my listview but there is a nameerror. Can you kindly advise if I am heading towards the right direction?